# Snapjs Drawer issue and scrolling content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, snap.js

I am using snap JS such that I have a drawer on the left and content to the right. However when the drawer is opened, I can still scroll content on the left.

What would be the right way so that I can disable the div on the left. In jQuery:

```
 if (state == 'right')
                  "disable the left side so you can't scroll' (  $('.idofelement').disable();)  ;
```

Is there something that I am overlooking in snap where within the controller the left can be disabled, without DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

in snap.js file

set this

`disable: 'left'`